# X509 certificate imported from certificate store has no private key

Tags: c#, .net-core, certificate, x509certificate2

There's some simple code to import a certificate with a private key into the Windows Certificate store using `.net core 2.2`:

```
  using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root,StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
  {
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
      store.Add(cert);
      store.Close();
  }
```

And some just as simple code to read it back out again:

```
 using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root,StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
 {
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, commonName, validOnly);
    store.Close();
    return certCollection;
 }
```

However although the certificate is successfully retrieved into the certCollection, it's private key is null and hasPrivateKey is false, even though they were not null and true on the prior `Add` call. Why is this?

**Update:**

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(keySize)) {    
     CertificateRequest certRequest = new CertificateRequest(
         subjectName,
         rsa,
         HashAlgorithmName.SHA512,
         RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

     certRequest.CertificateExtensions
         .Add(newX509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(certRequest.PublicKey, false));  
     return certRequest;
}
```

Comment: Windows doesn't expect certificates in the Root store to have associated private keys (and that if they do, there will be a copy which knows about the private key in the My store). It's possible that Windows is just erasing the associated key knowledge when saving it into the store.

Comment: It would be nice to see where `cert` came from in the first example.

Comment: @Crypt32 Cert is just an in memory X509Certificate2; created using C#.

Comment: @bartonjs The copy in the My store has no private key either and the My store read subsequently fails, if we want valid certificates only due to putting a CA cert in the My store.

Comment: “Created using C#” - created how? Opened from a PFX with the EphemeralKeySet flag? Using CertificateRequest? (If the latter, you probably didn’t make a persisted key, and ephemeral keys don’t persist in store adds)

Comment: @bartonjs You're right that's what I did do. I didn't realize setting keySize makes it ephemeral. That said if I use `RSA.Create()` which the documentation suggests is non-ephemeral then the outcome is no different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your key is being created as an ephemeral key, so when it's being added to a persisted store the key is being discarded.

If you want to persist the key into the store certificate, you either need to create it as a persisted key directly, or export to a PFX then re-import (which is the easiest form):

```
// If you're planning on saving to a LocalMachine store you should also | in the
// X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet bit.
X509KeyStorageFlags storageFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet;

X509Certificate2 certWithPersistedKey =
    new X509Certificate2(
        certWithEphemeralKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, ""),
        "",
        storageFlags);
```

Now `certWithPersistedKey` can be added like you expect.

Comment: Cool, I was specifically hoping you would see my question when I asked because i read a bunch of your other SO answers and github goodness and it was all excellent. So thanks. This also seems to have solved my secondary issue with creating an intermediary CA certificate, with the root CA cert. When i tried to sign End Entity certs with the intermediary they would fail saying the root CA had no key - more testing needed there but so far so good.

Comment: Actually for my second issue i needed to `certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);` as well since the create method using an issuerCertificate doesn't do this as is the case when creating a self signed cert. A good discussion about how `CopyWithPrivateKey` works can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19888

Answer (score 1):

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("a.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(xCertificate);
```

**Cause**
When the certificate is installed by using the X509Certificate or X509Certificate2 class, X509Certificate or X509Certificate2 by default creates a temporary container to import the private key. The private key is deleted when there's no longer a reference to the private key.

**Resolution**
To create a permanent key container for the private key, the X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet flag must be used to prevent .NET from deleting the key container. The following code should be used instead.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/framework/general/install-pfx-file-using-x509certificate